# Produce a line graph plotting the three most recent values for a series

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'll start with the most immediate problem that I'd like to solve, and then below that explain the XY problem in case that helps, or in case I've gone about solving it in a silly way.

I have a table like this in Excel:

| Car | -2 | -1 | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Volkswagen Golf 2013 | 20000 | 30000 | 40000 |
| Volkswagen Golf 2016 | 23000 | 60000 | 70000 |
| Volkswagen Polo 2008 | 67000 | 34000 | 39000 |
| Nissan Qashqai 2020 | 50000 | 120000 | 80000 |
| Nissan Micra 2018 | 40000 | 70000 | 9000 |

Imagine that "0" "-1" and "-2" stand in for "most recent", "second most recent" and "third most recent" - let's say that this is a table of cars sold by a second hand car dealer. The numbers in the table are the values for the mileage of the car when it was sold.

What I'd like to do, for this scenario, is plot the values of the mileage for the three most recent car types in a line graph. I don't really know how to explain this properly, so I'll draw a graph and hopefully illustrate the point.

I'd want the numbers -2 -1 0 to be on the X axis, and the mileage to be on the Y axis (so the highest mileage shown would be 120,000 here.

[image]

What I've tried so far:

1. Create the table in Excel as below, minus the "Car" heading:

[image]

2. Select the table, click Insert -> Line graph
3. Click "Select data"
4. Click "Switch row and column" to get the "time value" on the X axis.

However, I don't know how to get the numbers I want on the Y axis. Instead what happens is this:

[image]

How can I generate a graph that captures all of my car types as separate lines in the line graph, with the X axis showing the "time value" (-2, -1, 0) and the Y axis showing the mileage (the numeric values in the table?)

---

**The XY problem**

So the data I'm starting with actually looks like this (in the mock-up of my real solution anyway) ...

| Purchased | Make | Model | Year | Mileage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-14 | Volkswagen | Golf | 2013 | 20000 |
| 2023-02-11 | Volkswagen | Golf | 2013 | 30000 |
| 2023-01-28 | Volkswagen | Golf | 2013 | 40000 |
| 2023-02-25 | Volkswagen | Golf | 2016 | 23000 |
| 2023-01-03 | Volkswagen | Golf | 2016 | 60000 |
| 2023-01-01 | Volkswagen | Golf | 2016 | 70000 |
| 2023-02-23 | Volkswagen | Polo | 2008 | 67000 |
| 2023-01-20 | Volkswagen | Polo | 2008 | 34000 |
| 2022-12-28 | Volkswagen | Polo | 2008 | 39000 |
| 2023-02-24 | Nissan | Qashqai | 2020 | 50000 |
| 2023-02-15 | Nissan | Qashqai | 2020 | 120000 |
| 2023-02-10 | Nissan | Qashqai | 2020 | 80000 |
| 2023-02-23 | Nissan | Micra | 2018 | 40000 |
| 2023-02-12 | Nissan | Micra | 2018 | 70000 |
| 2023-02-01 | Nissan | Micra | 2018 | 9000 |

The first thing I decided to do was transform this data, by concatenating the three "grouping" columns (Make, Model and Year) into a single string, as I figured this would be easier to deal with. Then I converted the dates into "recency values", as I don't actually care what the real date was. I just want to show which car was sold "most recently", where most recently is 0, and anything less is -1, -2 etc. I've put these as column headings and transposed the mileage data, as I thought this would be easier to graph, but I'm still not able to get the visualisation I wanted.

So if there's a way to actually get the line graph I wanted from the original data set, rather than transforming the data, that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the label in cell `A1` (you can add it back later, it just makes things easier to not have it there)
2. Insert the line chart
3. Right-click on the chart and choose "Select Data" from the popup menu
4. Click on the "Switch row/Column" button and click OK
5. Add the label back in `A1`

Result with your data set:

[image]

Comment: You're describing more or less exactly what I described doing in the OP. I tried it again, but the result looks like the image I've shown in the OP, so I'm not actually plotting the numbers in the cells for some reason. I'm not really sure what's being plotted here.

Comment: See edit to my answer showing the chart with your data set